# creating a variable from sed output

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am banging my head against the keyboard on this simple piece of code.

```
#!/bin/bash
connstate="Connected"
vpnstatus=$(/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn state | (grep -m 1 'state:'))
echo $vpnstatus
vpnconn=$(echo $vpnstatus | sed -e 's/>>\ state: //g' | sed "s/ //g")
echo "$vpnconn"  "$connstate"
if [ "$vpnconn" = "$connstate" ];then
   echo $vpnconn 
   else echo "this script still fails"
fi
echo done
```

This is the output from the above code:

```
>> state: Connected
Connected Connected
this script still fails
done
```

I believe the issue revolves around the `vpnconn=$` if I comment that section of code out and fill the variable `vpnconn="Connected"` this code works fine. Something with how the sed is working on the input from vpnstatus and outputting the results to vpnconn is making what looks like a correct result incorrect when doing the compare in the if then.

I have tried splitting up the vpnconn line into two separate lines and that did not change anything, I took out the `sed "s/ //g"` and replaced it with a trim `-d ' '` and that did not change the results. I know this is something small in this tiny piece of code that I am missing.

Comment: What if the `$vpnconn` has some escape character in it which is suppressed by echo? like `\n` for example?

Comment: I suspect it's a whitespace issue. Try replacing `sed "s/ //g"` with `sed "s/[[:space]]//g"`?

Comment: I also think that the most likely problem is invisible characters in `$vpnconn`.  To see what is really there, replace `echo "$vpnconn"  "$connstate"` with `printf '%q %q\n' "$vpnconn"  "$connstate"`.  The fix suggested by @tsm should work, with a small modification: use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:space]]`.

Comment: Folks, we have a winner....

I suspect it's a whitespace issue. Try replacing sed "s/ //g" with sed "s/[[:space]]//g"? – tsm

Give this person a kewpie doll.

and pjh gets a nice handshake for the correction of tsm

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
vpnconn=$(echo "$vpnstatus" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Something like:

```
vpnstatus=$(/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn state|grep -m 1 'state:'|awk '{print 3}')
```

should do the work.